# Is there an app to ping IP's periodically to check latency?

Tags: software-recommendation, display, ping

I'm sure I came across a really nice app that would ping a list of sites or IP addresses every x mins/hours and send alerts when it could not ping.

But I can't find the app back, anyone know of any good ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this sends alerts, but it can monitor up to 250 IP addresses at whatever interval you like.  It can display the host, status (as green/yellow/red) and ping time.

On the app store for $1.99:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ping/id412751654?mt=12

Comment: Yeah this is the functionality I was after... but it's not the app I remember. I found another app call "sntop" which does what I want too but not in a nice GUI as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

How about a web service that will do this for you?

Check out [host-tracker.com](http://www.host-tracker.com).  It will ping an IP address (or http-get or traceroute) for you from a collection of sensor sites.  It looks like it will email you error notifications.

I haven't used the site, so can't speak to how well it works.

[image]

Comment: Not really... I need something to check that my local internet connectivity is working.